# Insert into mongo database does not work - why?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I try to set up some basic fixtures in Mongo DB. To do so I read a set of JSON files and try to insert them into local db (I am connecting with admin rights). Here's the weird part. For some reasons I wrote to versions of the code that should work basically the same so I have one:

```
$client = new \MongoClient($connectionURI);
$db = $client->selectDB($database);
$collections = $db->listCollections();

foreach ($collections as $collection) {
    //echo "Removing all documents from '$collection'" . PHP_EOL;
    $collection->remove();

    $tmp = explode('.', (string)$collection);
    $collectionName = $tmp[1];
    $tmp = explode('_', $tmp[0]);
    $dbName = $tmp[1];
    $country = $tmp[2];

    if(file_exists(__DIR__."/fixtures/{$country}/{$dbName}/{$collectionName}.json")) {
        echo "Inserting fixture data into '{$collection}'".PHP_EOL;
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/fixtures/{$country}/{$dbName}/{$collectionName}.json"));
        $doc = $collection->insert($data, ["w" => "majority"]);
    }
}
```

And second one based on iteration of the files to read instead of listing existing collections:

```
$client = new \MongoClient($connectionURI);
foreach(glob(__DIR__.'/fixtures/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
    $country = basename($dir);
    foreach(glob(__DIR__.'/fixtures/'.$country.'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dbDir) {
    $collections = array_diff(
        scandir(__DIR__."/fixtures/{$country}/".basename($dbDir)), ['.', '..']
        );

        $dbName = 'test_'.basename($dbDir).'_'.$country;

        foreach($collections as $collectionFile) {
            $collectionName = pathinfo($collectionFile)['filename'];

            $data = [];//json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__."/fixtures/{$country}/".basenam    e($dbDir)."/{$collectionName}.json"));
//            $client->$dbName->$collectionName->insert($data);
            $db = $client->selectDB($dbName);
            $collection = $db->selectCollection($collectionName);
            $collection->insert($data, ["w" => "majority"]);
            echo $country.'->'.$dbName.'->'.$collectionName.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is that the first implementation works nicely and second throws `MongoCursorException` with authentication problem. The problem I am having is that both versions try to connect to exact same database and collection in fact. So I am getting following output:

```
Inserting fixture data into 'test_customers_poland.accounts'
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'Couldn't get connection: Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: SASL Authentication failed on database 'test_customers_poland': Authentication failed.' in /srv/dev-api/src/tests/init_databases.php:96
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/dev-api/src/tests/init_databases.php(96): MongoCollection->insert(Array, Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /s
```

rv/dev-api/src/tests/init_databases.php on line 96

Of course I also checked running those snippets separately as well with the same result so the question is: what am I doing wrong in second approach?

Comment: In first case you are working with a single db. In the second you switch between dbs. What admin role exactly you are using to connect?

Comment: In both cases I switch databases in fact...

Comment: really? you must have posted wrong snippets then.

Comment: `$collectionName` variable in first code snippet consists in fact of `dbname`.`collection` - at least when I try to display the name...

Comment: That's cool, but you use this variable to read files only. You don't change db. You select it once, then iterate over all collections within this db, and do `$collection->insert` for each existing collection. On the second snippet you change database: `$client->selectDB()`.